# Problema con la resolución de pantalla Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Muy buenas a todxs! Es mi primerita vez aqui.
Os comento mi problema a ver si alguien quiere / puede ayudarme.
Me he comprado hace unos días un pc (hp 15s-eq1019ns) sin sistema operativo para practicar programación web.
Le he instalado Ubuntu como único sistema operativo y funciona todo menos la resolución de pantalla 1920x1080, asique probé a instalar Linux Mint (por si acaso con Mint si que funcionaba) pero tampoco.
He buscado en mil sitios, he seguido todos los tutoriales de youtube, pero nada.

Los distintos pasos que he seguido han sido los que aparecen en los foros:

- cvt 1920 1080 60
- xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
- xrandr --addmode eDP "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
- xrandr --output eDP --mode "1920x1080_60.00"

He creado el archivo .sh en .config con esa información, lo he hecho ejecutable al inicio, etc. y lo máximo que he conseguido es hacer que la resolución si aparezca en la lista de resoluciones disponibles, pero al seleccionarla y aplicar cambios me salta un error y se queda con la resolución "recomendada" por el sistema:

[image: Este es el error que me lanza al darle en aplicar los cambios]

Le he enchufado un monitor y en el monitor si me funcionan todas las resoluciones sin ningún problema. No entiendo nada.

Si alguien se anima a ayudarme, por favor que lo haga pensando que soy tonto, a ver si me entero de algo (soy noob en Linux).

Muchas gracias de antemano  :)

***** EDITO con un poco más de información del pc por si ayuda *****

**System**:    Kernel: 5.8.0-50-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Cinnamon 4.8.6
wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal

**CPU**:       Topology: Dual Core model: AMD Athlon Silver 3050U with Radeon Graphics bits: 64
type: MCP arch: Zen+ rev: 1 L2 cache: 1024 KiB

```
       Speed: 3194 MHz min/max: 1400/2300 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3194 2: 1277
```

**Graphics**:  Device-1: AMD Picasso vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus ID: 04:00.0
chip ID: 1002:15d8
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: amdgpu,ati unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa
tty: N/A
OpenGL: renderer: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.38.0 5.8.0-50-generic LLVM 11.0.0)
v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.6 direct render: Yes

Comment: La verdad es que me imagino que el problema son los drivers privativos de la gráfica. De hecho he mirado para instalárselos, pero este pc tiene una AMD Picasso y no encuentro esos drivers en ningún sitio. Los que me mandaste son de nvidia, no? Gracias igualmente

Answer (score 0):

ya probase desinstalado completamente los controladores privativos (apt purge nvidia-* desde la terminal).

prueba sino  los driver 384.111  [en este enlace](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Answer (score 0):

Estaba buscando una cosilla en stackoverflow en ingles y me salio la recomendación de mirar en el foro en español... y he decidido registrarme para intentar ayudar!

He estado buscando tu modelo de portatil en la web de hp ( https://support.hp.com/za-en/document/c06618111 ) y aparentemente la resolución nativa de tu portatil es 1366x768, por lo que sería el motivo por el que no te aparece 1920x1080 como opción, y aún forzando añadirla probablemente no obtendríamos un resultado aceptable de imagen.